# node-formidable and a simple progress bar

Tags: node.js

If I look into the node-formidable documentation I can read:

```
"Event: 'progress' (bytesReceived, bytesExpected)
Emitted after each incoming chunk of data that has been parsed. 
Can be used to roll your    own progress bar."
```

I am wondering how to implement my own progress bar I mean how to read that information client side? I am quite confused. Is it implemented with a polling GET that starts after the POST has started or is it possible to read the information from the POST request while uploading?

If I look at this:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(sys.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
  }
```

Look like the /upload url is handling the POST request and returning something res.write('received upload:\n\n');

My question is who can read that

```
res.write('received upload:\n\n');
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to override the `onPart` hook!

Just broadcast a message though socket at every form `progress` event callback call like this:

```
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
  var progress = {
    type: 'progress',
    bytesReceived: bytesReceived,
    bytesExpected: bytesExpected
  };

  socket.broadcast(JSON.stringify(progress));
});
```

than on client listen for socket messages.

Comment: @Giovanni Could you please give us some example in both Server and Client side about how to roll own Progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

A good options could be using [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO)

Remember to overwrite the `onPart` hook.

```
incomingForm.onPart = function(part) {
  part.addListener('data', function() {
    // send back to the client the status
  });
}
```

Comment: So you are suggesting to replace node-formidable with Socket.IO-node on server side for the whole uploading process?

Comment: ... I am getting it. The client make a POST request to a node-formidable then starts a socket.io session with a Socket.IO-node. On every part node-formidable receives it makes a callback to Socket.IO-node that broadcast to all clients. The clients need to filter only the messages regarding its own files. Something like this?

Comment: this could be a option. Another could be to store the progress server-side (db, json file) and the client asks for it by polling.

Answer (score 0):

Say, you are uploading something via AJAX, then you just need to bind a callback to `xhr.upload.onprogress` on client side:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    console.log(`${e.loaded} out of ${e.total} bytes have been uploaded`)
  }
}
```

Nothing required on server side. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload) for the full list of inject points. And tutorial [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob).