# Communication between PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sockets

I have a import friends button that when clicked loads friends from Facebook which is done through a post request to a `php` file.

Now how would I create a live progress bar?

I know how to make the progress bar itself, just not 100% sure how to do communications between `php` and the page in an easy way.

Comment: php<->js is basically AJAX.

Comment: though can you do that while the php script is running?

Comment: I need to send a notification to the js script every loop.

Comment: you can do a loading graphic like a spinning wheel etc..

Comment: Yup, though preferably I would like to have a progressbar, that updates every sec or so.
Friend imports can take up to 60 sec.

Comment: communication between php/server side and javascript/client side only happens after php has done it's work, so there's no way to tell what php's progress is until it's done.

Comment: you might want to check out node.js for something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323291/node-formidable-and-a-simple-progress-bar

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of. I know sockets could work, though thats a bit too complicated.

Comment: @SamKool You can try Server-sent events in that case. It can hold a long-open HTTP connection for pushing data and it's really easy to implant. It also has a polyfill for non-supported browsers. You can also try my PHP library for server-sent events. https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should consider server-sent events. It does not require a special server. The only thing it requires is a server that can serve HTTP requests which is a must for a web server.

The data will be sent in a long-holding HTTP connection. It's pretty easy to implant in PHP. All you need is a loop that echos the data in a specific format and flush the data out.

Server-sent events is a one-way communication between the server and the client so it'll be useful in your case.

To ease development, I've created a PHP library for server-sent events. You can consider using it: github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php

Hope my information can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Load all friends into JavaScript Array.

```
function import_friends(friend_array)
{
    var response=0;
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            response += xmlhttp.responseText;
            update_the_progress_bar(response,friend_array.length);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<friend_array.length; i++)
    {
     xmlhttp.open("post","url",true);
     xmlhttp.send(friend_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Your response from the URL you're passing the friend to should be, "1" for success. Then it's just simple division in the update function to update the bar.